# Getting columns ON CONFLICT without a DO UPDATE

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, common-table-expression, sql-returning

Trying to come up with best performing approach:

**Option 1**: using INSERT ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.start_gmail_user_session(
    input json, OUT user_session json)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  input_email varchar(80) := LOWER(TRIM((input->>'email')::varchar));
  input_first_name varchar(20) := TRIM((input->>'firstName')::varchar);
  input_last_name varchar(20) := TRIM((input->>'lastName')::varchar);
  input_phone varchar(23) := TRIM((input->>'phone')::varchar);
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO users (role, email, first_name, last_name, phone)
   VALUES ('student', input_email, input_first_name, input_last_name, input_phone)
   ON CONFLICT (email) DO UPDATE SET email = input_email
   RETURNING json_build_object('id', create_session(id), 'user', json_build_object('id', id, 'role', role, 'email', input_email, 'firstName', first_name, 'lastName', last_name, 'phone', phone)) INTO user_session;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Seemed to me that the `DO UPDATE SET email = input_email` just so I could get values from `RETURNING` isn't efficient.

**Option 2**: using FOUND

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.start_gmail_user_session(input json, OUT user_session json)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  input_email varchar(80) := LOWER(TRIM((input->>'email')::varchar));
  input_first_name varchar(20) := TRIM((input->>'firstName')::varchar);
  input_last_name varchar(20) := TRIM((input->>'lastName')::varchar);
  input_phone varchar(23) := TRIM((input->>'phone')::varchar);
BEGIN
  SELECT json_build_object('id', create_session(users.id), 'user', json_build_object('id', users.id, 'role', users.role, 'email', input_email, 'firstName', users.first_name, 'lastName', users.last_name, 'phone', users.phone)) INTO user_session FROM users WHERE email = input_email;
  IF NOT FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO users(role, email, first_name, last_name, phone)
      VALUES('student', input_email, input_first_name, input_last_name, input_phone)
      RETURNING json_build_object('id', create_session(id), 'user', json_build_object('id', id, 'role', 'student', 'email', input_email, 'firstName', input_first_name, 'lastName', input_last_name, 'phone', input_phone)) INTO user_session;
  END IF;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Option 1 was a little slower.

Is there a better way to do option 1 where I could use `DO NOTHING` instead of a bogus `DO UPDATE SET email = input_email`? The latter seemed to be the only way for the RETURNING to work.

Comment: You could use [FOUND](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) and if the query does not INSERT/UPDATE then just use the  `input_*` variables to build the JSON object.

Comment: Side note: the language name is an identifier and should not be enclosed in single quotes. Currently this syntax is accepted for backward compatibility but that might be removed in a future version.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Thanks for pointing that out about the language identifier. I initially did not put quotes around it but then used the latest pgAdmin to generate a CREATE script (and it put the quotes in even though left out when I created it). Probably a backward compatibility decision the pgAdmin team made but I'll adjust that above for correctness.

Comment: I would not worry about the quotes too much, when the function gets imported into Postgres 14+ the quotes will be removed automatically.